# Yum color=always option isn't working

Tags: centos, yum, configuration, colors

Running Yum (version 3.4.3) on a Centos 7.3.1611 system.

I've tried to enable colors on `yum` for a while now, with no luck.

**Here's what I've tried:**

1. Using the `--color=always` option on a command (e.g. `yum list installed --color=always`)
2. Adding `color=always` to `/etc/yum.conf`
3. In addition to adding that to `yum.conf`, specifying that as the configuration file when running a command (e.g. `yum list installed --config=/etc/yum.conf`)
4. Adding all specific color options to `/etc/yum.conf` (see here for the list: https://gist.github.com/jakebathman/aa1e4f6d5803ce6361dfd78e3d945e0c)

Other elements are able to be colored in the prompt, including `grep foo --color=always` and the prompt itself through `~/.bashrc`.

I can't figure out what's going wrong. Any additional thoughts or things to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be `color=on` instead of `color=always` in `/etc/yum.conf`.

Comment: Wow, that's dumb. `man yum.conf` says "Possible values are: auto, never, always", but you are 100% right. Much thanks.

Comment: The man page is right, the values "auto", "never", and "always" are used in the command line itself using `--color=`, but, you cannot use them in the conf file.

Comment: The man page for `man yum` says that, but so does the page for `man yum.conf`. I'll get in touch with someone to report it.

Comment: That's a good idea..